# ASP.NET Session remains '0'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, session-state

I have a masterpage that has this code in it:

```
<script runat="server">



    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        If Session("userid") = Nothing Then
            txtLoginUser.Visible = True
            txtLoginPass.Visible = True

        Else


            Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True")
            Dim useridComm As String = "SELECT name, surname FROM users WHERE user_id=@userid"
            Dim sqlUserID As New SqlCommand

            conn.Open()

            Dim userid As String = Session("UserID")

            sqlUserID = New SqlCommand(useridComm, conn)
            sqlUserID.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", Convert.ToInt32(userid))
            Dim datareader As SqlDataReader = sqlUserID.ExecuteReader()

            datareader.Read()
            If datareader.HasRows Then



                userid = Session("UserID")

                lblLoggedIn.Text = "[Welcome, " + datareader("name").ToString() & " " & datareader("surname").ToString() + " ]"
                txtLoginUser.Visible = False
                txtLoginPass.Visible = False
                lblUsername.Visible = False
                lblRegister.Visible = False
                btnLogin.Visible = False
                lblUsername0.Visible = False


            End If
            datareader.Close()
            conn.Close()

        End If
    End Sub

   Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim loginSQL As New SqlCommand
        Dim loginComm As String

        Dim CommonFunctions As New CommonFunctions()
        Dim dec_pass As String = CommonFunctions.EncryptPassword(txtLoginPass.Text.Trim)

        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True")


        loginComm = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username=@username and password=@password"

        conn.Open()


        loginSQL = New SqlCommand(loginComm, conn)
        loginSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtLoginUser.Text.ToString)
        loginSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", dec_pass)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = loginSQL.ExecuteReader()
        dr.Read()


        If dr.HasRows Then
            Session("UserID") = dr("user_id")

        ElseIf dr.HasRows = False Then

            lblRegister.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            lblRegister.Text = "Incorrect Username/Password."
        End If


        dr.Close()
        conn.Close()

        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")

    End Sub
</script>
```

On Button1 click the script should get the user_id by using the `datareader` and create a `Session("UserID")` and pass it to `Default.aspx`. `Default.aspx` then gets the `Session("UserID")` and searches for a `user_id` that has the same value and checks the roles using `user_roles` table, and if the `role_id` is 4 then `tblAdmin` is shown, otherwise, it isn't.

This is the code for Default.aspx:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page



    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


        Dim UserID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Session("UserID"))

        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim userTypeCommand As String = "SELECT role_id FROM users_role WHERE user_id=@UserID"
        Dim userTypeSQL As New SqlCommand

        conn.Open()

        Try

            userTypeSQL = New SqlCommand(userTypeCommand, conn)
            userTypeSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID)

            Dim datareader As SqlDataReader = userTypeSQL.ExecuteReader

            If datareader("role_id").ToString = "4" Then

                tblAdmin.Enabled = True
                tblAdmin.Visible = True

            ElseIf datareader("role_id").ToString IsNot "4" Then

                tblAdmin.Visible = False

            End If



        Catch ex As Exception



        End Try


        conn.Close()


    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnCreateArticle_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreateArticle.Click


        Response.Redirect("addArticle.aspx")

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnAdmin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdmin.Click
        Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx")
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I debug, after I press the 'Login' button the user_id (Session('UserID') remains 0, when the user_id of the user I used to log with is '12' in the table.

What Am I doing wrong?

I am using ASP.NET/VB.NET and SQL Server 2012.

Comment: tried this? Session("UserID") =Convert.ToInt32(dr("user_id"))

Comment: @aliassce Yes, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Had a missing `datareader.Read()`.